# insert image in the end of item

Tags: includegraphics, awesome-cv

I write a resume and I would like to add a QR code into it.

I use the following template for my resume - [link](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/gonzalo-ulla-resume/whxxyndxvdfr).

My resume line looks like this:

[image]

I had like it insert the QR right after the (added QR) so it will shift a little bit the line underneath it and to be like this:

[image]

I cant figure out how to include the graphic there. The code looks like this:

```
  \cventry
    {XXX}     % Organization
    {Founder and CEO} % Job title
    {XXX}          % Location
    {2021 - To Date}  % Date(s)
    {
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
        \item {Founded ....YYY (added QR)}
        \item {Developed ... ZZZ}
        \item {Took an ... XXX}
      \end{cvitems}
      
    }
```

and the code for cventry is:

```
% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-3.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
  \end{tabular*}%
```

So far I have managed to do something like this but now I just need to make the date aligned:

[image]

```
\newlength{\photowidth} 
\setlength{\photowidth}{1.5cm}
\newcommand*{\cventryqr}[6]{
\vspace{-2.0mm}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}

\begin{minipage}[c][][t]{\textwidth -\photowidth - 0.2cm} % <===========
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 5.2cm} R{5.2cm}}
\ifempty{#2#3}
  {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
  {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
  \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
\multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
\end{tabular*}%
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}[c]{\photowidth} 
\includegraphics[width=\photowidth]{#6}
\end{minipage}
}
```

any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Exactly what do you want to align the date with?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find definitions of L and R (column types) so I used p. Nor could I find definitions for `\ifempty`, `\entrypositionstyle`, `\entrydatestyle`, `\entrytitlestyle`, `\entrylocationstyle`. `\entrypositionstyle` nor `cvitems` so I commented them out.  I take it these are all from awesome-cv template on github (I don't do templates or github).

This aligns the tops of the tabular* and image.  `\ht\strutbox` is the distance from the baseline to the top for text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\newlength{\photowidth} 
\setlength{\photowidth}{1.5cm}
\newcommand{\cventryqr}[6]{%
\vspace{-2.0mm}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}

\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth -\photowidth - 0.2cm}% modify \textwidth
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}[t]%
  {@{\extracolsep{\fill}} p{\dimexpr \textwidth - 5.2cm} p{5.2cm}}
%\ifempty{#2#3}% coonot find
  %{\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
  %{\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
  %\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
  #2 & #3 \\ #1 & #4\\
%\multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
\multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth}}{#5}
\end{tabular*}%
\end{minipage}\hfil
\raisebox{\dimexpr \arraystretch\ht\strutbox-\height}{\includegraphics[width=\photowidth]{#6}}%
}
\begin{document}
\cventryqr
    {XXX}     % Organization
    {Founder and CEO} % Job title
    {XXX}          % Location
    {2021 - To Date}  % Date(s)
    {
      \begin{itemize} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
        \item {Founded ....YYY (added QR)}
        \item {Developed ... ZZZ}
        \item {Took an ... XXX}
      \end{itemize}
      
    }
    {example-image}
  \end{document}
```